# Integral: $\int x \arctan (1/x) dx$

Tags: integration

In fluid mechanics, to evaluate the influence on the stream function of a linear source distribution, I need to determine this integral:
$$\int x \arctan \bigg(\frac{a}{b-x}\bigg)\mathrm{d}x$$
I tried to integrate this by parts, but thirty years on from school maths I'm pretty rusty! Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Do you know integration by parts?

Comment: What can make life computationally less annoying is the fact that $$\arctan\left(\frac{a}{b-x}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2} + \arctan\left(\frac{x-b}{a}\right)$$ Since this is what is going to be differentiated in integration-by-parts anyway, the appearance of the constant $\frac{\pi}{2}$ isn't going to matter, but it makes the derivative less painful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=b-a\cot t \implies dx= a\csc^2 t dt$, then
$$I= \int x \tan^{-1} \frac{a}{b-x} dx= \int a (b-a\cot t) \csc^2 t dt=\int [ab \csc^2t- a^2\cot t \csc^2t] dt$$
Next, integration of first term is direct and for the second pne put $\cot t =u$ to get:
$$I=-a bt\cot t+\frac{a^2}{2}\cot^2 t +C$$

Comment: Thanks very much @dr-zafar-ahmed-dsc, but is it possible that this solution is for the integral without the initial $x$, i.e. the integral of arctan(a/(b-x)) dx?

Comment: @pancake Thanks, you are right now I have done the required, please see.